# validating the mutlicast port range

Tags: sockets, port, multicast, multicastsocket

I need to write a client server code. the client can send\receive packets from multiple  multicast addresses and also should check the validity of those IP\port range before sending\receiving packets.

so I looked on the  `RFC-5771 IANA Guidelines for IPv4 Multicast Address Assignments` and found the range of multicast IP addresses.

where can I find the range of legal (not taken by other application) multicast ports?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are no ports specific to multicast.  You can use any free UDP port available.